# Bitwise Shift to MSB in One Byte Added to Itself

Tags: c, types, dns, bitwise-operators

I am reading a book, "Network Programming with C" by Lewis Van Winkle and I discovered a line of code in Chapter 5, page 153 that I do not understand the value of. The context is around DNS resolutions through a header. What is the value or practical application of the following code:

```
/* msg[] is unsigned char*/
const int qdcount = (msg[4] << 8) + msg[5]
```

I understand that int is a wider type than char but why is the extra precision of value, for hardware interfacing at the firmware level if you choose to go deeper or what? To me, it appears that the grouped object would resolve to a value of the external object since shifting 8 bits is equal to one byte thus making it effectively just a product of itself with two, but why even use this method instead of just using:

`2 * msg[5]`

Not sure where to start looking for a solution because the problem is not clear.

Comment: It's extracting a 16-bit bigendian value from the message and storing it in a variable with native endianness for further processing.

Comment: It's unclear where you get the idea `2 * msg[5]` from. There is only one of them in the least 8 bits of the result.

Comment: @WeatherVane re: `2 * msg[5]`... Change the frame of reference. OP's confusion stems from "shifting the window" to the right, rather than "shifting the bits to the left"... What would be 8 bits to the right of msg[4]??? Answer: msg[5], of course....

Comment: Shifting eight bits multiplies by 256, not 2.

Comment: For context on DNS, RFC1035 §4.1.1 where this definition is given: "QDCOUNT         an unsigned 16 bit integer specifying the number of
                entries in the question section." appearing after 32 bits of other content in the header, hence the `4`  and `5` position for `msg` that is most probably bytes.

Comment: Isn't (msg[4] << 8) == msg[5]? To me that would yield the same expression, perhaps the bitwise shift operator yields a value as an expression from initial bit to length of shift? This would imply: bit = [2]; (msg[4] & (bit[n]<<0)) << 8; due to need to define where the shift happens and which binary value to shift... Does '<<' imply an MSB shift or perhaps means the code segment with respect to the operator '<<' is to mean a least significant shift because the relational operator '<' means  'a<b' therefore the left-hand side operant bound and associated as less than the right-hand side operant?

Comment: The actual size may be any length supported by architecture, i.e. bit[n] as 0 or 1 may be a long which would contain 2^sizeof(long) values or 8*sizeof(long) bits as a string in case you wanted to shift an expression as a group of bits however it would then need to support truncation from the MSB such that zeroes aren't accidentally overwriting the object r-val. and as such the bit-value would be a mask superimposed at some point and specified with the initial starting position then shifted across the binary string representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg[4]` contains the most significant eight bits out of a 16-bit number. `msg[5]` contains the least significant eight bits.

`msg[4] << 8` takes byte containing the most significant of 16 and shifts it left eight positions so they are in the positions of the most significant eight bits of 16. Then `+ msg[5]` puts the byte containing the least significant bits in the low eight bits of the 16. This reconstructs the 16-bit number that `msg[4]` and `msg[5]` came from.

`msg[4]` and `msg[5]` generally could not be loaded in a single load of a 16-bit integer because C code may execute in implementations in which the more significant byte is in the higher-addressed byte, not the lower-addressed byte and also because of type and aliasing rules in the C standard.

Comment: @"Eric Postpischi" I interpreted it as: '(msg[4] << 8) == msg[5]' and then assumed that if that was the case then since: a = b, a+b = (2a or 2b) then: (2 * msg[5] == msg[4] + msg[5]) but one method is with regards to an address and the other the value it seems. This may sound a bit naive but would something that creates an object for reuse with: char * header = malloc(sizeof(*header * 2) + 1); header = &char[4]; header[sizeof(*header * 2) + 2] = '\0' or via memcpy() be a viable solution or does it have effects that would be adverse to the intended function?